# Some of the fetch that are using forEach() not showing

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

I'm making this web app with API from https://www.football-data.org/

So I make the template for the API content with the DOM, but there's one part that are not being shown.

```
function showStanding(data) {
  let standings = ``;
  const standingElement = document.getElementById("standings");
  /* Jika dilihat melalui console.log, seharusnya kakak me looping data.standings[0].table, karena
disitulah object team berada
  */
  data.standings[0].table.forEach((standing) => {
    console.log(standing);
    standings += `
        <div class="standing__team">
            <div class="favtim">
            <img src="${standing.team.crestUrl.replace(
              /^http:\/\//i, 'https://')}" alt="Logo team" />
            <h3><a class="link" href="#team?id=${standing.team.id}">${standing.team.name}</a></h3>
            <h3 class="point">Point: <span>${standing.points}</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
  });

  // di line ke 23 dan 24 seharusnya competition, bukan competitions
    standingElement.innerHTML = `
  <div class="standing__header blue lighten-3">
            <h1>${data.competition.name}</h1>
            <p class="standing__header--place">${data.competition.area.name}</p>
            <p class="standing__header--time">${data.season.startDate} - ${data.season.endDate}</p>
        </div>
  `;
  document.querySelectorAll(".link").forEach(function (link) {
    link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      urlTeamParam = e.target.getAttribute("href").substr(9);
      loadpage();
    });
  });


}
```

So this is the code for the templating the API:

[image: the result]

So in the result there are a element which is base on the URL. but there's one part that are not showing.

So I tried to `console.log()` it and it appear on the console. How can I show it in the browser window?

[image: the console]

Can you help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I see no where in the code provided you are populating `standings` but you are doing `standings[0]`

Comment: @auliamnaufal you didn't use `standings` anywhere.

Comment: i loop the first standings

Comment: o yeah you right.